# Converting point kriging surface to small polygon data set?

Tags: interpolation, kriging

I have a dataset showing soil samples as points and the nutrient contents at each of these sample locations.

I have created an interpolation surface that represents the distribution of nutrients across my study area.

Within my study area are a number of smaller blocks or polygons. I want to either create new polygons or update an attribute of the existing polygons to represent the mean results from the interpolated surface generated from the point samples. The polygon blocks are equivalent to the vegetative block shown in the image below

A result similar to those generated from areal interpolation would be great but the aeral tool can only handle aeral interpolated.

Currently using ArcGIS 10

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Could you show a picture of what you have so far to give us a better idea?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: I have now updated the post. cheers